# How does one solve this ODE using a differential operator and a series expansion?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am solving a fairly basic non-homogeneous ODE, but I wanted to try using the differential operator, and a series expansion in order to find the particular solution. I am fairly convinced it is possible to solve an ODE using this method, however I an unable to understand how.

This is what I have done thus far:

$$
\begin{align*}
2y' + y &= \cos x \\
\end{align*}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
(2D+1)y &= \cos x \\
\end{align*}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
y &= \frac{\cos x}{2D+1} \\
\end{align*}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
y &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (2D)^{2n} \cdot (1 - 2D) \cdot \cos x \\
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\begin{align*}
y &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (2D)^{2n} \cdot (\cos x + 2\sin x)
\end{align*}
$$

How do I proceed from here? I cannot spot any mistake I have made in anything I have done leading up to it, but trying to proceed seems almost impossible. Have I completely misunderstood how derivative operators work?

I tried to solve using maclaurin series as well:
$$
\begin{align*}
2y' + y &= \cos x \\
\end{align*}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
(2D+1)y &= \cos x \\
\end{align*}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
y &= \frac{\cos x}{2D+1} \\
\end{align*}
$$
$$
y= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} D^n \cdot(\cos x)
$$

If the non-homogeneous function was a polynomial $x^n$ I could proceed by setting the upper bound as $n$ and evaluating (since subsequent terms have a differential operator of higher order than $n$ which will therefore annihilate the polynomial). But once again I do not know how to proceed from here for $\cos(x)$ since the derivative is cyclical.

I am aware of the [Exponential response formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_response_formula), but I want to try solve without it.

Comment: This is equivalent to the (simpler) geometric series expansion is 
$$
\frac{1}{1 + 2D} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-2D)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-2)^n D^n 
$$

Comment: @SammyBlack: That works if you’re willing to work with complex exponentials, but if you just want to use $D^2\cos x=-\cos x$ and $D^2\sin x=-\sin x$ then you need to expand in $D^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$2y'+y=\cos x$

$(2D+1)y=\cos x$

$(D^2+1)(2D+1)y=0$

$(2D^3+D^2+2D+1)y=0$

$y=c_1e^{-x/2}+c_2\sin x + c_3 \cos x$

$2y'=-(c_1)e^{-x/2}+2c_2 \cos x - 2c_3 \sin x$

$\cos x = (2c_2+c_3)\cos x +(c_2-2c_3) \sin x$

$c_2=2c_3, 5c_3=1\implies c_3=1/5, c_2=2/5$

$y=c_1e^{-x/2}+(2/5)\sin x +(1/5)\cos x$

---

$y=\frac{1}{1+2D}\cos x=(1-2D+4D^2-8D^3+...) \cos x$

$y=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-2D)^k\cos x$

$y=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-2D)^{4k}\cos x+\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-2D)^{4k+1}\cos x+\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-2D)^{4k+2}\cos x+\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-2D)^{4k+3}\cos x$

$y=\sum_{k=0}^\infty16^k \cos x+ \sum_{k=0}^\infty (2)\cdot 16^k \sin x + \sum_{k=0}^\infty  -4\cdot 16^k\cdot \cos x+ \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-8)\cdot 16^k \cdot ( \sin x) $

If I"ve accurately represented the procedure, the result is:

$y=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-3)\cdot 16^k \cos x + (-6)16^k \sin x$ It's interesting the sin and cosine term still maintain a 2:1 ratio.

I'm not sure this can be reconciled with the solution from above.

---

Additional solution method:

$2y'+y=\cos x$

$y'+(1/2)y=(1/2)\cos x$

$(ye^{x/2})'=\cos x \cdot e^{x/2}$

$ye^{x/2}=\int \cos x e^{x/2}dx$

$u=\cos x . du =-\sin x. dv=e^{x/2}. v= 2e^{x/2}$

$ye^{x/2}=2e^{x/2}\cos x+\int 2e^{x/2} \sin x dx$

$u=\sin x. du = \cos x. dv=2e^{x/2}. v=4e^{x/2}$

$ye^{x/2}=\int \cos x e^{x/2} dx = 2e^{x/2} \cos x +4e^{x/2} \sin x-\int 4e^{x/2} \cos x dx$

$\int \cos x e^{x/2} dx = (2/5)e^{x/2} \cos x +(4/5)e^{x/2} \sin x +c_1$

$y=c_1e^{-x/2}+ (2/5) \cos x + (4/5) \sin x$

Check:

$(2D+1)y = (2/5) \cos x + (-4/5)\sin x+(4/5) \sin x +(8/5) \cos x=2\cos x $

This suggest we need half the y initially tried. (because of a lost factor of one half on step 3).

$y=c_1'e^{-x/2} + (1/5)\cos x + (2/5) \sin x$

---

Found an operator method, but not sure how to express $1/(1+2D)$ in equivalent terms.

$2y'+y=\cos x$

$y'+(1/2)y=(1/2)\cos x$

$(ye^{x/2})'=(1/2)\cos x \cdot e^{x/2}$

$ye^{x/2}=\int (1/2)\cos x e^{x/2}dx$

$Py=e^{x/2}y$

$D(Py)=P[(1/2)\cos x]$

$Py=D^{-1}P(\cos x/2)$

$y=P^{-1}D^{-1}P(\cos x/2)$

$y=P^{-1}D^{-1}(\cos x e^{x/2}/2)$

$y=P^{-1} [(2/5)e^{x/2}\sin x+(1/5)e^{x/2}\cos x +c_1]$

$y=c_1e^{-x/2}+(2/5)\sin x + (1/5) \cos x$

Answer (score 1):

You are working outside the radius of convergence of the geometric series.

You get a result without further series computation by using that $(D^2+1)\sin x=0$ etc., that is, using
$$
\frac1{1-4D^2}=\frac1{5-4(D^2+1)}=\frac15\frac1{1-\frac45(D^2+1)}
$$
etc.